# Pattern matching in .collect: refer to current element?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have the following code, which works well:

```
val encodedItems = patterns.collect {
  case ParsedItem(s, p, o, true) =>
    EncodedItem(encode(s), encode(p), encode(o))
}
```

I would, however, like to refer to the current item in `patterns` to use it in a function argument and have tried something like the following:

```
val encodedItems = patterns.collect {
  case item: ParsedItem(s, p, o, true) =>
    EncodedItem(encode(s), encode(p, item), encode(o))
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't compile.

If I just write `case item: ParsedItem =>` it will work and I can use the `item` variable. However, I would like to ensure that the last argument is `true` as in the first code block and I want to keep the `s`, `p` and `o` variables.

Is there a syntax to do all these things together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@` to get a reference to the full object that's being matched.

```
val encodedItems = patterns.collect {
  case item @ ParsedItem(s, p, o, true) =>
    EncodedItem(encode(s), encode(p, item), encode(o))
}
```

Comment: Fantastic – I feel like I will never manage to learn about all the syntactic sugar that Scala offers. Thank you.